# Error on conecting with PostgreSQL database: 'System.Memory, Version=4.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'

Tags: postgresql, powerbi, npgsql

I'm trying to connect Power BI to a PostgreSQL database and the following error appears:

> Se produjo un error al leer datos desde el proveedor: 'No se puede
>   cargar el archivo o ensamblado 'System.Memory, Version=4.0.1.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' ni una de sus
>   dependencias. El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado.'"

I have a database in localhost and already instaled the latest MSI and followed the steps form this post:

https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Community-Blog/Configuring-Power-BI-Connectivity-to-PostgreSQL-Database/ba-p/12567

I've tried everything and till doesn't work.

Anyone can help me?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall the latest version of npgsql and install version 4.0.3. It is a bug that comes in 4.0.4 and 4.0.5, it will be compiled until 4.0.6